# Batching Python Gmail API : AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'resumable'

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api

I am encountering the following error when I perform a batch.add() with a Gmail API request.

Error:

```html
if request.resumable is not None:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'resumable'
```

```html
for searchResultPart in searchResultParts: 
    batch = BatchHttpRequest() 
    batch2 = BatchHttpRequest()
    for msgID in searchResultPart: #Loop through each messageID
        request1 = service.users().messages().get(userId=userID, id=msgID).execute()
        request1.update({"resumable" : None}) #TRIED THIS DOES NOT WORK
        request2 = service.users().messages().modify(userId=userID, id=msgID, body={'removeLabelIds': ['UNREAD']}).execute()
        batch.add(request=request1,request_id=msgID) #Fetch the message
        batch2.add(request=request2,request_id=msgID) #Mark the fetched messages as read
    batch.execute() 
    batch2.execute()
```

I tried adding a key : request1["resumable"] = None
I tried adding an attribute : request1.resumable = None

I tried searching for other solutions, but I'm stuck. What can I do to resolve this?

The error that I am seeing is occurring during the batch.add(request=request1,request_id=msgID).

To my understanding, the reason why this occurs is because you cannot fetch payloads with batching. Therefore, batching expects resumable to be unassigned with None.

Comment: Okay, so the problem was the .execute() at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
  for searchResultPart in searchResultParts: 
      batch = BatchHttpRequest() 
      batch2 = BatchHttpRequest()
      for msgID in searchResultPart: #Loop through each messageID
          request1 = service.users().messages().get(userId=userID,id=msgID)
          body = {'removeLabelIds': ['UNREAD']}
          request2 = service.users().messages().modify(userId=userID, id=msgID, body=body)
          batch.add(request=request1, callback=self.theEmailCallback,request_id=msgID) #Fetch the message
          batch2.add(request=request2,request_id=msgID) #Mark the fetched messages as read
      batch.execute() 
      batch2.execute()
```

Notice how its the same, except I removed the .execute() from request1 and request2. Now I no longer receive this error.